# row dictionary will flush after commiting sqlalchemy session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am updating a row of sqlite3 using sqlalchemy. In the code bellow `result` will be empty after commiting session.

I solved it with the commented line `result.append(copy.deepcopy(row))` but this question still remains for me.

```bash
def update_bg_classifier_result(self, isvalid, final_cat, version, groups_id):
    result = list()
    try:
        for group_id in groups_id:
            try:
                row = self.classifier_categories_db_session.query(ClassifierCategories)\
                    .filter_by(group_id=group_id)\
                        .filter_by(version=version)\
                            .one()
                row.isvalid = isvalid
                row.final_cat = final_cat
                # result.append(copy.deepcopy(row))
                result.append(row)
            except Exception as e:
                if str(e)=='No row was found when one was required':
                    continue
        self.classifier_categories_db_session.commit()
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        extra_msg = {
            "last_exec_line": str(exc_tb.tb_lineno),
            "error_message": str(e),
        }
        self.logger.error(msg="databaseFetcherError", extra={"in_app_msg":extra_msg})
        raise Exception(extra_msg)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: why the `result` variable will be flush after commiting session?

Comment: By "empty" and "flushed", do you mean that the objects have been [expired in commit](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.expire_on_commit).